# How to update the npm dependence formidable to install ionic/cli

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ionic-framework

When i ran sudo npm install -g @ionic/cli

then i got this message:

> npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest,
> formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes:
> https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/blob/master/VERSION_NOTES.md
>
> changed 212 packages, and audited 213 packages in 35s
>
> 26 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities

then i tryed with "npm install formidable@latest" and "npm install formidable@v2" and "npm install formidable@v3" without solution.

i recived the next message:

> robinsonalvarez@MBP-de-Madeline ~ % sudo npm install formidable@v2
>
> up to date, audited 218 packages in 554ms
>
> 28 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities

finally i could't update or install a new formidable version

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue here..

- If you require formidable in your project, you can do an `npm install formidable@v2`
- If you have other packages that require formidable as a dependency, You may want to check the package with `npm ls formidable` and then troubleshoot if the authors of that package have updated their dependency to the latest one. Or raise an issue if not

In my case, it was `chai-http` and as on now they still have an open PR to update the projects dependencies.